# Nokogiri: replace newlines and spaces with `<br>` and `&nbsp;` inside `<pre>`

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

A certain downstream sink (that I don't control), being fed w/ html, ecstatically trims down all spaces & newlines into 1 space. Thus I need to 'escape' such chars inside all `<pre>` tags.

I've managed to 'protect' newlines by replacing them w/ `<br>`, but the spaces issue stupefies me:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment "<pre><code>  1\n\n  2</code></pre>"
doc.css('pre').each do |node|
  text = node.to_s.gsub(/\n/, '<br>').gsub(/\s/) { '&nbsp;' }
  node.replace Nokogiri::HTML.fragment text
end

puts doc
```

still yields in:

```
<pre><code>  1<br><br>  2</code></pre>
```

(instead of expected `<pre><code>&nbsp;&nbsp;1<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;2</code></pre>`)

i.e., Nokogiri re-encodes `&nbsp;` to spaces again!

Now, here's what also interesting: those are not actual 'spaces', but (I gather) UTF8 non breaking space chars:

```
$ ruby 1.rb | hexdump -C
00000000  3c 70 72 65 3e 3c 63 6f  64 65 3e c2 a0 c2 a0 31  |<pre><code>....1|
00000010  3c 62 72 3e 3c 62 72 3e  c2 a0 c2 a0 32 3c 2f 63  |<br><br>....2</c|
00000020  6f 64 65 3e 3c 2f 70 72  65 3e 0a                 |ode></pre>.|
0000002b
```

notice `c2 a0 c2 a0 31` (`<nbsp><nbsp>1`) instead of more common `20 20 31`.

I don't think its prudent to blindly enforce non-UTF8 encoding on my output, so playing w/ various encodings isn't an option.

Comment: Can you list what you're desired output html output is?

Comment: `<pre><code>&nbsp;&nbsp;1<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;2</code></pre>`

Comment: Can't be done unless you change the encoding. See: https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/416

Comment: Or you could always run the `gsub` after the `to_s` on the node instead.

Comment: This is a tough one.  If you can't use `Nokogiri.HTML(html.encode('ASCII-8BIT'))` then you may need to deal with raw string data after parsing what you need from Nokogiri. You may wanna open an issue.  https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+encoding